# Installing Zend Framework 2 skeleton application on Apache Web server

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2

I've got this issue with installing ZF2 application on my Apache server. I am running PHP 5.3.5.

The composeer.phar self-update works fine then when I try to install dependencies it comes up with this:

```
C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\zf2-tutorial>phpcomposer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependences <including require-dev>
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- zendframework/zendframework 2.3.1 requires php >=5.3.23 -> no matching package found
```

Its saying my PHP isn't updated. But my phpinfo() shows i am running 5.3.5. Has anyone else had this problem?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Like the error says, ZF 2.3 requires PHP **5.3.23** or above. You have **5.3.5**. You either need to be running a more recent version of PHP, or install ZF 2.2.x instead which will work with your version.

Comment: Some more explanation: 5.3.5 is like 5.3.05 when you, the OP, compare it to 5.3.23.

Comment: Cheers, can't believe i missed that. Setting up new apache server and latest PHP now. Thanks for the help.